# python- print doesn't show output on console on bootup

Tags: python, shell, openwrt, autostart, rc

I working on openwrt and I want to run a python script on bootup. For this, I have written my script and added it to `/etc/rc.local`. After bootup, when i do `ps xa`, I can find the script running but nothing prints on screen.
The steps I have followed are below -

**bootpython.py - python script that needs to run on bootup**

```
i=0

while(i<100):
        print("HELLO \n")
        i+=1
```

**script.sh - Script added to rc.local**

This script checks if there's wlan0 in ifconfig and only then, it runs the python code. After reboot, there's saved.txt file created and it has HELLO written in it. But `/usr/bin/python3 /root/bootpython.py &` doesn't print anything on screen. If i run the script without booting the system (`/root/script.sh`), it prints HELLO on screen. What am i missing here?

```
a=0

while [ $a -lt 100 ]
do
        if ( ifconfig | grep wlan0 )
        then
                a=`expr $a + 1`
                /usr/bin/python3 /root/bootpython.py > /root/saved.txt &
                /usr/bin/python3 /root/bootpython.py &
                break
        fi
done
```

**/etc/rc.local**

```
# Put your custom commands here that should be executed once
# the system init finished. By default this file does nothing.

/root/script.sh &

exit 0
```

Comment: That's because the script output isn't linked to your terminal, it started in background by the system, even before you log in, and I suppose it's output isn't sent to anywhere, or maybe you can find it in `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/boot.log`

Comment: @Havenard: But then how do i print my output onto the terminal?

Comment: I suppose the easiest way is to put it in `/root/.bashrc` instead of `/etc/rc.local`, so it will run in your terminal as you log in instead of running on system init, this way you should see the script's output.

Comment: There's a way to run it in system init and then make it detect when the root log in and dump the output to it's `/dev/tty*` but that's a rabbit hole you'll probably want to avoid...

Comment: @Sourabrt try this module: curses "https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html".

Comment: As an aside, `if ( ifconfig | grep wlan0 )` should be `if ifconfig | grep -q wlan0`